# Can we rank K-Means clusters or assign weights to certain clusters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I am working on a K-Means Clustering task and I am wondering if there is some way to do some kind of ranking of clusters, or maybe assign specific weights to some specific clusters.  Is there a way to do this?  Here is my code.

```
from pylab import plot,show
from numpy import vstack,array
from numpy.random import rand
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\my_path\\analytics.csv')

data = np.asarray([np.asarray(dataset['Rating']),np.asarray(dataset['Maturity']),np.asarray(dataset['Score']),np.asarray(dataset['Bin']),np.asarray(dataset['Price1']),np.asarray(dataset['Price2']),np.asarray(dataset['Price3'])]).T

centroids,_ = kmeans(data,1000)
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)

details = [(name,cluster) for name, cluster in zip(dataset.Cusip,idx)]
```

So, I get my 'details', I look at it, and everything seems fine at this point.  I end up with around 700 clusters.  I'm just wondering if there is a way to rank-order these clusters, assuming 'Rating' is the most important feature.  Or, perhaps there is a way to assign a higher weight to 'Rating'.  I'm not sure this makes 100% sense.  I'm just thinking about the concept and wondering if there is some obvious solution or maybe this is just nonsense.  I can easily count the records in each cluster, but I don't think that has any significance whatsoever.  I Googled this and didn't find anything useful.

Comment: You should look into [`Gaussian Mixture Models`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html) for clustering. It is similar to K-means, but instead each cluster is a multi-variate Gaussian with some probability that a point is sampled from that Gaussian at all. Therefore each point has some "rating" to each cluster.

Comment: Interesting.  I've heard about this, but I don't really know anything about it.  I guess it's time to learn a couple new tricks.

Comment: Can i ask *why* you want to rank clusters? and what would you be ranking them by?

Comment: It was just a random thought.  It may not make sense to do this because K-Means is an unsupervised exercise and I feel like this one piece is adding in a supervised component.  I'm just trying to get some guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "cheat" trick would be to use the feature `rating`twice or three times, then it automatically gets more weight:

```
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(dataset['Rating']), np.asarray(dataset['Rating']), np.asarray(dataset['Maturity']),np.asarray(dataset['Score']),np.asarray(dataset['Bin']),np.asarray(dataset['Price1']),np.asarray(dataset['Price2']),np.asarray(dataset['Price3'])]).T
```

there are also adjustments of kmeans around, but they are not implemented in python.

Comment: I thought of that too.  I guess that's all there is and that's good enough.  Thanks so much!!